A problem with the placement of an element in the constraint laoyut
I use a guide line to design the screens in the application, and for some reason when I try to place an image it doesn't place it well
The code I have a problem with
 `<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/SingleLayout_yesOrNo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_qu"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/SingleLayout_gl_imgYesOrNo_Low"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/SingleLayout_gl_imgYesOrNo_Right"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/SingleLayout_gl_imgYesOrNo_Left"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/SingleLayout_gl_imgYesOrNo_Up"
    />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/SingleLayout_gl_imgYesOrNo_Left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/SingleLayout_gl_imgYesOrNo_Right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.55" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/SingleLayout_gl_imgYesOrNo_Up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.38" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/SingleLayout_gl_imgYesOrNo_Low"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.44" />`

I checked the code several times and I can't find the problem, and the rest of the code works
A photo of the problem
I want the image to be inside the marked square
what i want

When you use ConstraintLayout and set constraints on a view, you generally want the layout_width to be 0 if you set start and end constraints and the layout_height to be 0 if you set top and bottom constraints.
